# Issue in running user-data script AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to run python script through AWSCLI (user-data). I tried but it didn't run and i have following in my logs

```
boot.log:2015-08-07 10:08:30,660 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: './step-1
cloud-init.log:2015-08-07 10:08:30,660 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: './step-1'
cloud-init-output.log:2015-08-07 10:08:30,660 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: './step-1'
```

Note step-1 is my script which i am trying to pass as user-data . Also my script is present in same directory from  where i am running command so it should pick

Comment: Can you post the actual command and parameters?

Comment: It seems that your script does not specify the shell it is supposed running in. I mean, #!/bin/bash e.t.c.

Answer (score 18):

The default interpreter seems to be Python. So if you simply want to execute a shell script you'll need to start with a hash-bang, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
/yourpath/step-1
```

Please note, in order to debug this, try: cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
And see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts

Answer (score 3):

You can use any command to be run under `user-data`. I have used `user-data` to bootstrap Windows Instances with Domain Controller setup or domain join using PowerShell; of course given that it is on EC2 - the properties are extensible whether you are running in Unix based or Windows Based.

So you have specified, Python - so please ensure the following

1. Python already installed and then take an image - use that image to bootstrap
2. You enable User-Data and pass the user-data commands during the launch time

Comment: "aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-XXXXX --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name PPPPPPP --security-group-ids LLLLL --subnet-id KKKKKK --user-data file://script.py"


works on linux but not on windows any idea about it??

Comment: where did u place the script.py - which location ? Or trying giving the full path [ absolute path of the script.py ]

Comment: I have a doubt that if the AMI is enabled with User Data - can launch a plain ec2 instance and enable the user data and then take the ami and try using that AMI ?

Comment: enabling user-data is only for windows ? how do we enable it ?

Comment: check this out - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html

Comment: i checked the user-data check box but when i reboot it disappears any reason?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

the document from aws say that only shell and cloud-init directive that are supported

Comment: I believe userData is handled by cloud-init.

Comment: My case, I forgot start with "#!/bin/bash"

Comment: Like @rmsys, in my case, I missed the '#' character on the shebang.