# docker not installed through yum in user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

this is how my user data looks like, but docker is not installed, when connecting to my ec2 machine:

```
sudo yum -y install docker
sudo service docker start
sudo docker pull nginx
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using user-data script you can debug what is happening by ssh connecting to the instance and check the output in `cloud-init-output.log`.

`sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

When doing this you'll find an strange error containing:

`Jan 29 11:58:25 cloud-init[2970]: __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'sudo yum -y install dock...'`

Which means that the default interpreter seems to be python and it's neccesary to start the user-data with `#!/bin/bash`. ([See this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875598/issue-in-running-user-data-script-aws-ec2))

When changing the user-data to:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo yum -y install docker
sudo service docker start
sudo docker pull nginx
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

it will be executed as expected and you will find nginx running on your ec2.